# SQL additional column or Many To One relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a Product entity and each product have a type, let's say phone or laptop, so it is better to create product entity with column "type":

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)
```

Or create a table just for the type and make a Many To One relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    type_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES type(id)
)

CREATE TABLE type(
    id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
)
```

Comment: If you have a one-to-many relationship, then you have two entities and a junction table is appropriate.

Comment: so i have to use the second method ? which one is more logical and with better performance ?

Comment: It depends on what 'Type' means in your design, if it is only an attribute to display together with the product go for the first solution but if it is associated with some business logic or you think you might expand on it beyond having a name then go for the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a product can have multiple types, then the correct relationship is three tables.  In your case, you have only a single type.

The reason the second method is better is because it enforced the types, with a proper foreign key relationship.  So, you don't have to worry about one row being `'phone'` and another `'Phone'`.  You have the explicit list of types available.

If this is going into an application, than such a list is even more important, because it feeds directly into elements of the UI where you want lists of types, such as pick-lists.

Answer (score 0):

If your products have just one type, there's nothing to be gained and much to be risked in terms of additional, unnecessary complexity by introducing an Additional tabls. Type should in the same table, be varchar in the table and enum in the java with the @Enumerated (String) annotation.